# STS randomly highlights the code yellow making it difficult to work

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I am unable to figure the setting which could turn off the random highlighting of code with yellow which makes it very difficult to work. The java class has no compilation errors and also code coverage is not enabled. Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: When you hover the light bulb in the ruler on the top left, what does it say?

Comment: There is no light bulb for the yellow highlight. The lightbulb you see is for the line my cursor is and is not lit and provides no suggestions.

Comment: Tried to remove **all** coverage executions?

Comment: I have never seen anything like this in a plain STS4 distribution installation. Do you have any additional plugins installed? And do you have any steps how to reproduce this?

Comment: There is no steps for reproduction as it is random behavior. I have not installed any plugins over the distribution installation. I am using STS 4.7 release.